# Sequence path in CONSTRUCT CSPARQL query is failing

Tags: sparql, rdf

Hy I am trying to add a sequence path in a SPARQL CONSTRUCT query.
The query is then registered in a CSPARQL engine.

My aim is to find a pattern of triples and convert them to a new resource of a different schema.

Here is an example of a query which is failing:

```
        REGISTER STREAM read AS
        PREFIX rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>  +
        PREFIX a: <http://sample/vocab/log#>
        PREFIX e:  <http://sample/vocab/event#>
        CONSTRUCT {
                e: rdf:type             e:Event;
                   e:id                 ?id;
                   e:name               \"ReadEvent\";
                   e:timestamp          ?timestamp;
                   e:hasFile/e:filename ?file;
                   e:content            ?message .
             }
        FROM STREAM <ws://localhost:8124/tw/stream> [RANGE 5s STEP 3s]
        WHERE {
           ?entry a:id            ?id .
           ?entry a:accessCall    ?access .
           ?entry a:timestamp     ?timestamp .
           ?entry a:file          ?file .
           FILTER ( str(?access) = \"read\" ) .
           ?entry a:message      ?message .
        };
```

The following part seems to cause an issue:

> e:hasFile/e:filename ?file;

Because I am getting the following error on startup:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "/" "/ "" at line 5, column 170.
Was expecting one of:
<IRIref> ...
<PNAME_NS> ...
<PNAME_LN> ...
<BLANK_NODE_LABEL> ...
<VAR1> ...
<VAR2> ...
"true" ...
"false" ...
<INTEGER> ...
<DECIMAL> ...
<DOUBLE> ...
<INTEGER_POSITIVE> ...
<DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
<DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ...
<INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ...
<DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ...
<DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ...
<STRING_LITERAL1> ...
<STRING_LITERAL2> ...
<STRING_LITERAL_LONG1> ...
<STRING_LITERAL_LONG2> ...
"(" ...
<NIL> ...
"[" ...
<ANON> ...

at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.perform(ParserSPARQL11.java:102) ~[jena-arq-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.parse$(ParserSPARQL11.java:53) ~[jena-arq-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.SPARQLParser.parse(SPARQLParser.java:34) ~[jena-arq-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.parse(QueryFactory.java:148) ~[jena-arq-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:80) ~[jena-arq-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:53) ~[jena-arq-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at eu.larkc.csparql.sparql.jena.JenaEngine.parseSparqlQuery(JenaEngine.java:557) ~[csparql-sparql-jena-0.9.7.jar:na]
at eu.larkc.csparql.core.engine.CsparqlEngineImpl.registerQuery(CsparqlEngineImpl.java:324) ~[csparql-core-0.9.7.jar:na]
at ac.at.tuwien.logparser.services.CSparqlStreamService.initCSparqlEngine(CSparqlStreamService.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to find any examples of a CONSTRUCT query that uses sequence paths or any information on that.

My questions are now:

- Are sequence paths supported by SPARQL in a CONSTRUCT?
- Are there any alternatives to my approach?

Appreciate any possible help! thanks!

Comment: why do you put the property path into the template part of the `CONSTRUCT` query? That can't work. Do `e:hasFile [e:filename ?file] ;` if you reallywant some anonymous node for the file attached with the filename

Comment: by the way, any reason for using an ancient Jena version? Ok, I can see you're using CSPARQL, you should poke the people to update their project. (which seems to be untouched since 2015) ... here is a fork with Jena 3: https://github.com/wherget/CSPARQL-engine/tree/jena-3 - though even that should update their Jena deps.